# Mapping elements for a relation? And Unmapping them to solve a problem

Tags: linear-algebra, discrete-mathematics

I am doing discrete math and it’s a little confusing (May be over thinking.)

$A=\{0,-1\}$ and Relation $R=\{(x,y)\in A \times  A \mid  x^2 + y^2 = 1\}$.

My elements would be $(0,-1)$ and $(-1,0)$ correct? And the domain/codomain would be $(0,-1)$?

I just can’t figure out how to map it and the range?